# Why does my dynamically changing link not work? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am making a flash site that changes it download link everytime a button is selected on the page to the corespronding flash file for download. The weird part is I got this working perfectly but after a week of working on the project it just stopped and I have no idea why any input would be great.

```
     $(document).ready(function () {
            var links = [
        'swfs/#1%20(Special%20Japanese%20Extended%20Dance%20Mix).swf',
        'swfs/$D6.swf',
        'swfs/(MAD)%20Huh.swf'
        ];

         var displaytext = [
        '#1 (Special Japanese Extended Dance Mix)',
        '$D6',
        '(MAD) Huh'
        ];

        var c = 0;
            var flashmovie, test, temp;

            function init() {
                flashmovie = document.getElementById('flashmovie');
                document.getElementById('back').onclick = function () {
                    if (c == 0) {
                        c = links.length;
                    }
                    c--
                    displayFiles();
                    download();
                }

                document.getElementById('next').onclick = function () {
                    if (c == links.length - 1) {
                        c = -1;
                    }
                    c++;
                    displayFiles();
                    download();
                }

                document.getElementById('rand').onclick = function () {
                    temp = c;
                    while (c == temp) {
                        c = Math.floor(Math.random() * links.length);
                    }
                    displayFiles();
                    download();
                }

// Scripts for the left and right arrow key functionality
        document.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
            if (e.which == 37) {
                $("#back").click();
            }
        });

        document.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
            if (e.which === 39) {
                $("#next").click();
            }
        });

            }

            function displayFiles() {

                test = links[c].substring(links[c].lastIndexOf('.') + 1, links[c].length);
                document.getElementById('title').innerHTML = displaytext[c];

                flashmovie.innerHTML =
                    '<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="' + links[c] + '">' +
                    '<param name="movie" value="' + links[c] + '">' +
                    '<\/object>';
            }

            function download() {
                document.getElementById('downLink').setAttribute('href', links[c]);
                document.getElementById('downLink').setAttribute('download', displaytext[c]);
            }

            window.addEventListener ?
                window.addEventListener('load', init, false) :
                window.attachEvent('onload', init);
        });
```

HTML

```
<body>

    <div class="titleText">
            <h1>Anon Curb</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="flashmovie" class="flashMovieSamp">
        <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="swfs/welcomeflash.swf">'+
            <param name="movie" value="http://www.anon-curb.com/swfs/welcomeflash.swf">
        </object>
    </div>
    <!-- end #container -->
    <div id="buttonCon">

        <div id="buttons">
            <button id="next">next</button>

            <button id="rand">Random</button>

            <button id="back">Back</button>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div id="titleCon">
        <a href="swfs/welcomeflash.swf" class="downLink" download="welcomeflash">
            <div id="title">Hit random button</div>
        </a>
    </div>

        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-beta1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="js/flashcollection.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Did you try turning it off and back on again?

Comment: I tried doing that but then sparks starting flying out of the mouth of the machine don't know how to fix it though I'll call frank though he might have an idea

Comment: Haha! :) Seriously though, you should specify in what way it is not working

Comment: Well 2 weeks ago I got it working completly then when i checked on it today (don't know how long its been) it only downloads the initial i set the "welcome flash" not the value thats suposed to take the href and download attribute after a button is selected

Comment: Take out the $(document).ready({ and the corresponding })

Comment: Why would I take out that?

Comment: You're not actually using it.  You're already waiting to run your `init()` function until the `load` event, so it's redundant.

Comment: No I'm using it and the problem was an id/class confusion i did

Comment: From a quick glance at your code I'm almost positive it's redundant, but I'm glad your problem is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is function download(), you tried to get the element by Id "downLink", but there is no id assigned of that tag in HTML, so I add the id='downLink' to the tag now. The downlink works fine now.

Just a bit suggestions: as you already have the jQuery involved, you can probably use the jQuery selector when dealing with DOM. It will be more convenient also helps to keep the consistency of code.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var links = [
        'swfs/#1%20(Special%20Japanese%20Extended%20Dance%20Mix).swf',
        'swfs/$D6.swf',
        'swfs/(MAD)%20Huh.swf'
    ];

    var displaytext = [
        '#1 (Special Japanese Extended Dance Mix)',
        '$D6',
        '(MAD) Huh'
    ];

    var c = 0;
    var flashmovie, test, temp;

    function init() {
        flashmovie = document.getElementById('flashmovie');
        document.getElementById('back').onclick = function () {
            if (c == 0) {
                c = links.length;
            }
            c--
            displayFiles();
            download();
        }

        document.getElementById('next').onclick = function () {
            if (c == links.length - 1) {
                c = -1;
            }
            c++;
            displayFiles();
            download();
        }

        document.getElementById('rand').onclick = function () {
            temp = c;
            while (c == temp) {
                c = Math.floor(Math.random() * links.length);
            }
            displayFiles();
            download();
        }

// Scripts for the left and right arrow key functionality
        document.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
            if (e.which == 37) {
                $("#back").click();
            }
        });

        document.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
            if (e.which === 39) {
                $("#next").click();
            }
        });

    }

    function displayFiles() {

        test = links[c].substring(links[c].lastIndexOf('.') + 1, links[c].length);
        document.getElementById('title').innerHTML = displaytext[c];

        flashmovie.innerHTML =
            '<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="' + links[c] + '">' +
            '<param name="movie" value="' + links[c] + '">' +
            '<\/object>';
    }

    function download() {
        document.getElementById('downLink').setAttribute('href', links[c]);
        document.getElementById('downLink').setAttribute('download', displaytext[c]);
    }

    window.addEventListener ?
        window.addEventListener('load', init, false) :
        window.attachEvent('onload', init);
});
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-beta1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/flashcollection.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>
<div class="titleText">
    <h1>Anon Curb</h1>
</div>
<div id="flashmovie" class="flashMovieSamp">
    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="swfs/welcomeflash.swf">'+
        <param name="movie" value="http://www.anon-curb.com/swfs/welcomeflash.swf">
    </object>
</div>
<!-- end #container -->
<div id="buttonCon">

    <div id="buttons">
        <button id="next">next</button>

        <button id="rand">Random</button>

        <button id="back">Back</button>
    </div>

</div>

<div id="titleCon">
    <a href="swfs/welcomeflash.swf" class="downLink" download="welcomeflash" id="downLink">
        <div id="title">Hit random button</div>
    </a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Omggggg thats like legit the tenth time ive done something like that in the past year on a project. I really really really need to start paying more attention to that but thank you sir for picking out my dumbness :D

Comment: @cosmichero2025, making use of the "Inspect" and "console" in chrome/firefox will benefit debugging.  :)